# Is it possible to create a python script on cloud which runs everytime an API gets updated?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a Twitter bot which tweets every time the buyer info gets updated. I have an API for buyer info so what I am asking is can I create a twitter bot using python that tweets every time the API gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Install tweepy into your Python API, then run a function on API calls

[Post tweet with tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19337672/2308683)